# Save .xls file in Java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I made an application that reads some data in a timer from hour to hour. I used jxl library.

There are two Excel files. One from where my application reads the data and another that it is used by a person to enter some of data in the first one. The data entered by that person is entered between two reads of my application. This is made using Excel formulas. My problem is that when my application opens the file, the data entered by that person isn't read. It's automatically `0`. But if I open the file and hit Save before my application, the data is than read.

So I'm thinking that I need somehow to open, save and read the file from my code. I don't know how to save the file from code. Here is how I read the cells:

```
                    o9 = sheet1.getCell(14, numCell);
                    p9 = sheet1.getCell(23, numCell);
                    x9 = sheet1.getCell(15, numCell);
                    y9 = sheet1.getCell(23, numCell);
                    z9 = sheet1.getCell(25, numCell);
                    // g6 = sheet1.getCell(6, 36);
                    //  G6 = sheet1.getCell(6, 37);
                    r9 = sheet2.getCell(17, numCell);
                    s9 = sheet2.getCell(18, numCell);
                    t9 = sheet2.getCell(19, numCell);
                    ab9 = sheet2.getCell(27, numCell);

                    try {
                        if (o9.getType() == CellType.STRING_FORMULA) {
                            FormulaCell nc14 = (FormulaCell) o9;
                            // System.out.println(o9.getContents());

                        } else {
                            alimMoara = Double.parseDouble(o9.getContents());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        txtComent.setText("Alim Moara hasn't been saved !");
                    }

                    if (x9.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        NumberCell nc23 = (NumberCell) x9;
                        incarcMoara = nc23.getValue();

                    }

                    try {
                        if (z9.getType() == CellType.STRING_FORMULA) {
                            FormulaCell nc24 = (FormulaCell) z9;
                            String formula = nc24.getFormula();

                        } else {
                            SSB = Double.parseDouble(z9.getContents());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        txtComent.append(" SSB hasn't been saved ");
                    }

                    if (r9.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        NumberCell nc17 = (NumberCell) r9;
                        ventSepA = nc17.getValue();

                    }

                    if (ab9.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        NumberCell nc27 = (NumberCell) ab9;
                        turSep = nc27.getValue();
                    }
```

Some thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK formulars could not yet be read from excel.

Comment: What are AFAIK formulars?

Comment: formulars are cells containing formulars like this: `=$A$1 * 2`, so if the cell A1 has the value `5` the official result would be `10`. Using JXL you can not read 10, you would read `=$A$1 * 2` instead.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK  ;-)

Comment: I read the values of the formulas just fine. The problem is that 2 of the cells that contain string formulas that bring the values from another excel file. Those 2 cells i cannot read except if i hit the save buton before my aplication opens and reads the data

Comment: thx Christian. I'm ashamed I did not know that beacause I am not that old :))